# Get all possibilities from group of values

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-core

I have this list of objects:

```
 List<PayloadItem> items = new List<PayloadItem>()
            {
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Size",Option="S"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Size",Option="M"},

                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Red"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Green"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Blue"},

                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Width",Option="100"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Width",Option="200"},

                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="10000"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="20000"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="30000"},
            };
```

where the model of "PayloadItem" is:

```
internal class PayloadItem
    {
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        public string Option { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have a main object called "Product" contains a property called "AttributeValues":

```
internal class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<AttributeValue> AttributeValues { get; set; }
    }
    internal class AttributeValue
    {
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

what I need is creating a list of **all possible** products with the next steps: 
1- the product will get all its properties (except attribute values) from outside product object, so no need to take care about them.
2- each product will contain values from the list "items" where the values will not be the same with another product (at least one attribute value will be different), and the product must have attribute values from all attributes.
*for example:*

```
{
product1:
{ AttributeValues:[
  {
   Attribute:'Size',
   Value:'M'
  },
  {
   Attribute:'Color',
   Value:'Red'
  },
  {
   Attribute:'Width',
   Value:'100'
  },
  {
   Attribute:'Length',
   Value:'10000'
  }
 ]
},
product2:
{ AttributeValues:[
  {
   Attribute:'Size',
   Value:'S'
  },
  {
   Attribute:'Color',
   Value:'Green'
  },
  {
   Attribute:'Width',
   Value:'200'
  },
  {
   Attribute:'Length',
   Value:'20000'
  }
 ]
}
}
```

**Note** 
the process is the same is creating variant products from an existing product in Shopware

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple recursive algorithm.  See :

```
    class Program
    {
        static List<List<AttributeValue>> possible = new List<List<AttributeValue>>();
        static string[] uniqueAttributes = null;
        static List<PayloadItem> items = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            items = new List<PayloadItem>()
            {
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Size",Option="S"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Size",Option="M"},

                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Red"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Green"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Blue"},

                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Width",Option="100"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Width",Option="200"},

                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="10000"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="20000"},
                new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="30000"},
            };
            uniqueAttributes = items.GroupBy(x => x.Attribute).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
            Recursive(0, null);
            print();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Recursive(int index, List<AttributeValue> attributes)
        {
            List<PayloadItem> payloadItems = items.Where(x => x.Attribute == uniqueAttributes[index]).ToList();
            foreach (PayloadItem payloadItem in payloadItems)
            {
                List<AttributeValue> newAttributes = new List<AttributeValue>();
                if (attributes != null) newAttributes.AddRange(attributes);
                newAttributes.Add(new AttributeValue() { Attribute = payloadItem.Attribute, Value = payloadItem.Option });
                if (index == uniqueAttributes.Length - 1)
                {
                    possible.Add(newAttributes);
                }
                else
                {
                    Recursive(index + 1, newAttributes);
                }
            }
        }
        static void print()
        {
            int productCount = 1;
            foreach(List<AttributeValue> attributes in possible)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("product" + productCount);
                foreach (AttributeValue attribute in attributes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   Attribute: {0}, Value: {1}", attribute.Attribute, attribute.Value);
                }

                productCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<AttributeValue> AttributeValues { get; set; }
    }
    public class AttributeValue
    {
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    internal class PayloadItem
    {
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        public string Option { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It works, but for some reason it is consuming lot of resources especially the memory.

Comment: How big is you input?  Writing to file instead of putting in c# object will reduce memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can find a nicer way to implement this, but here is an approach without the use of recursion.

The items are first grouped by their `Attribute` value. Each group hence contains a subset of the items. Now, each resulting `Product`'s `AttributeValues` will contain *one item from each group*. For each `Product`, the composition of items from each group is different. We keep track of which item to select from which group by keeping track of and properly updating each group's *current item index*.

The idea is that you keep track of the current item index within each group, and update it everytime you have generated a `Product`.

You'd typically start with the first item (i.e. with index `0`) in each group, which means that the first `Product`'s `AttributeValues` would be created based on the following item subset:

> [0] {Attribute="Size",Option="S"},
> [0] {Attribute="Color",Option="Red"},
> [0] {Attribute="Width",Option="100"}
> [0] {Attribute="Length",Option="10000"}

The next collection of items would typically be that the last group's current item index increases by 1. That leaves us with the following item subset:

> [0] {Attribute="Size",Option="S"},
> [0] {Attribute="Color",Option="Red"},
> [0] {Attribute="Width",Option="100"}
> [1] {Attribute="Length",Option="20000"} <-- current item index has been increased by 1

, and so on.

When we reach the point where the last group's current item index needs to reset to `0` (because we have reached the last item in that group and need to 'start over'), we make sure to increase the current item index of the group *directly left of* the last group.

This kind of logic goes for each group that is not the last group: If *all* groups right of any group have reached their 'last item index', then the group in question will need to increase its 'current item index' by 1. Simultaneously, all the groups right of that group will reset their 'current item index' to `0`.

An example:

> [0] {Attribute="Size",Option="S"},
> [1] {Attribute="Color",Option="Green"},
> [1] {Attribute="Width",Option="200"}, <-- last item index of group
> [2] {Attribute="Length",Option="30000"}, <-- last item index of group

In the next iteration, the two last 'current item index' values have been reset to `0`, and the 'current item index' of the group directly left of those two groups is increased by 1:

> [0] {Attribute="Size",Option="S"},
> [2] {Attribute="Color",Option="Blue"}, <-- current item index has been increased by 1
> [0] {Attribute="Width",Option="100"}, <-- current item index has been reset
> [0] {Attribute="Length",Option="10000"} <-- current item index has been reset

We create a `Product` list and populate it iteratively. Each iteration consists of:

1. Finding the new product's `AttributeValues`, which consist of *one item from each group* and is selected based on the 'current group item indices'
2. Creating the new product, with those `AttributeValues`
3. Calculating the next 'current group item indices' (basically, updating the item index of the last group, and possibly also of one or more groups left of the last group)

   - To make sure we always 'loop' the indices within the available item index range for each group, we can use modulo (`%`) to calculate the updated index value

A possible implementation of this approach could be:

```
private static int _groupCount;
private static int[] _lastItemIndices;
private static int[] _currentItemIndices;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<PayloadItem> items = new List<PayloadItem>() { ... };
                
    List<Product> products = GetProductsFor(items);
}

private static List<Product> GetProductsFor(IEnumerable<PayloadItem> items)
{
    var groupedItems = items
        .GroupBy(item => item.Attribute)
        .ToList();
    
    var groupedItemsWithGroupIndex = groupedItems
        .Select((gr, index) => (Items: gr.ToList(), GroupIndex: index));
    
    var itemCounts = groupedItems
        .Select(gr => gr.Count())
        .ToList();
    
    int productCount = itemCounts
        .Aggregate(1, (acc, next) => acc * next);
    
    _groupCount = itemCounts.Count;
    
    _lastItemIndices = itemCounts
        .Select(count => count - 1)
        .ToArray();
    
    _currentItemIndices = new int[groupedItems.Count];
    
    var products = new List<Product>();
    
    while (products.Count < productCount)
    {
        var attributeValues = groupedItemsWithGroupIndex
            .Select(gr => gr.Items[_currentItemIndices[gr.GroupIndex]])
            .Select(AttributeValue.FromPayloadItem)
            .ToList();
        
        products.Add(new Product
            {
                Name = "Product " + (products.Count + 1),
                Description = "Description " + (products.Count + 1),
                AttributeValues = attributeValues,
            });
        
        // Update _currentItemIndices
        for (var i = 0; i < _currentItemIndices.Length; i++)
        {
            if (IsLastGroup(i) || AllSucceedingGroupsHaveReachedLastItem(i))
            {
                _currentItemIndices[i] =
                    (1 + _currentItemIndices[i]) % (1 + _lastItemIndices[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return products;
}

private static bool IsLastGroup(int index)
{
    return index == _groupCount - 1;
}

private static bool AllSucceedingGroupsHaveReachedLastItem(int index)
{
    var itemIndexDeviancesFromLastIndex = _currentItemIndices[(index + 1)..]
        .Zip(_lastItemIndices[(index + 1)..],
             (currentItemIndex, lastItemIndex) => lastItemIndex - currentItemIndex);
    
    return itemIndexDeviancesFromLastIndex
        .All(itemIndexDeviance => itemIndexDeviance == 0);
}
```

For this implementation, I have extended the `AttributeValue` class as follows:

```
internal class AttributeValue
{
    private AttributeValue(PayloadItem payloadItem)
    {
        Attribute = payloadItem.Attribute;
        Value = payloadItem.Option;
    }
    
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    public static AttributeValue FromPayloadItem(PayloadItem payloadItem)
        => new(payloadItem);
}
```

If you populate `items` as you have suggested in the question post:

```
List<PayloadItem> items = new List<PayloadItem>()
{
   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Size",Option="S"},
   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Size",Option="M"},

   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Red"},
   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Green"},
   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Color",Option="Blue"},

   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Width",Option="100"},
   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Width",Option="200"},

   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="10000"},
   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="20000"},
   new PayloadItem{Attribute="Length",Option="30000"},
};
```

, the result for the provided input is a list of 36 `Product` objects:

> Product 1 (Description 1)
> Attribute: Size | Value: S
> Attribute: Color | Value: Red
> Attribute: Width | Value: 100
> Attribute: Length | Value: 10000
>
> Product 2 (Description 2)
> Attribute: Size | Value: S
> Attribute: Color | Value: Red
> Attribute: Width | Value: 100
> Attribute: Length | Value: 20000
>
> Product 3 (Description 3)
> Attribute: Size | Value: S
> Attribute: Color | Value: Red
> Attribute: Width | Value: 100
> Attribute: Length | Value: 30000
>
> Product 4 (Description 4)
> Attribute: Size | Value: S
> Attribute: Color | Value: Red
> Attribute: Width | Value: 200
> Attribute: Length | Value: 10000
>
> ...
>
> Product 35 (Description 35)
> Attribute: Size | Value: M
> Attribute: Color | Value: Blue
> Attribute: Width | Value: 200
> Attribute: Length | Value: 20000
>
> Product 36 (Description 36)
> Attribute: Size | Value: M
> Attribute: Color | Value: Blue
> Attribute: Width | Value: 200
> Attribute: Length | Value: 30000

An example fiddle is found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oQbuIh).